# xcode to compile programs

Tags: c, xcode, redirect, terminal

I'm starting out trying to get to grips with CS- learning the basics of C using a book recommended by a friend "A book on C" by *Al Kelley and Ira Pohl*. I am using Xcode OSX El Capitan on a Mac.

I am trying to test one of the examples of code they are using to illustrate the scanf() function, heres the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double  x, min, max, sum, avg;

    if (scanf("%lf", &x) !=1){
        printf("No data found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    min = max = sum = avg = x;
    printf("%5s%9s%9s%9s%12s%12s\n%5s%9s%9s%9s%12s%12s\n\n",
           "Count", "Item", "Min", "Max", "Sum", "Average",
           "-----", "----", "---", "---", "---", "-------");
    printf("%5d%9.1f%9.1f%9.1f%12.3f%12.3f\n",
           1, x, min, max, sum, avg);

    for (i = 2; scanf("%lf", &x) == 1; ++i) {
        if (x < 2)
            min = x;
        else if (x > max)
            max = x;
        sum += x;
        avg = sum / i;
        printf ("%5d%9.1f%9.1f%9.1f%12.3f%12.3f\n",
                i, x, min, max, sum, avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To test the program I tried to build it in Xcode and got this error:

!Screen Shot 2016-08-17 at 18.02.42.png

I realise its probably a very basic problem probably caused by incorrect settings in Xcode becasue I compiled the file in Terminal and it compiled just fine.

My second question relates to compiling in Terminal. I successfully compiled the program using "cc running_sum.c" but when I type in the command "running_sum < data" (to redirect the input to another text file with some values") the program cant find the values and prints "no data found" as it should when nothing is found.

Can anyone kindly enlighten me how to solve the problem with Xcode build errors and secondly how to correctly redirect the input of the file in Terminal (and xcode too as that would be useful in the future).

Many thanks,

Luca

Comment: Build failures in Xcode can be found in the warning/error list of the main project tree (left side by default of the Xcode UI). Fourth icon from the left, looks like a little triangle. Click it, You can then click each (or all) of your warnings/errors and copy them to the clipboard, then paste them in your question. We can't see your screenshot, so you may as well fix it by doing this right.

Comment: Sorry you cant see the print screen, this is the error:

Comment: export arch=x86_64
    export variant=normal
    /usr/bin/make

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2